# "TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable"

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and need help in solving the error which I am not able to fix
Imma writing function called checkCoupon which verifies that a coupon code is valid and not expired.
A coupon is no more valid on the day AFTER the expiration date. All dates will be passed as strings in this format: "MONTH DATE, YEAR".
'''

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
def check_coupon(entered_code, correct_code, current_date, expiration_date):
    current, expire = dt.strptime(current_date, '%B %d, %Y'), dt.strptime(expiration_date, '%B %d, %Y')
    if entered_code in correct_code and expire >= current:
        if correct_code == False:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

check_coupon(0, False, 'September 5, 2014','October 1, 2014')

'''
```

> TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Comment: The error message is because correct_code is not a list in your if statement here ```if entered_code in correct_code and expire >= current:```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `entered_code` in `correct_code` and that performs "0 in False" for the values provided to the function and hence causes the error as you cannot iterate through a boolean value. If you wish to check the validity of the coupon from a list/set of existing coupons, replace the `correct_code` with a list/set of existing and valid coupons.

Comment: Thank Yor! I figured it out!